# How to use Multiple Databases in Django Application using Database Router

Tags: python, django, database

Am trying to implement multiple Database support for my django Existing appplication.I have already tried the approach provided in dajngo offical documentation.
But my requirement is quite diffrent from what the documentation has stated.

In a django functions, you could call request.session.['user'] and perform actions based on that. In my case, I would like to be able to switch databases depending on the session varaible assigned at the time of login.

Is there anyway to inject a request/session call into the db_for_read() and db_for_write() methods like in the following

```
class DataBaseRouter:
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if request.session['user'] == "Some value":
            return "master"
        return "default"

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if request.session['user'] == "Some value":
            return "master"
        return "default"
```

I am using Django 2.0.1 currently, and I have tried the following code, am not sure it's a correct approach or not, following is what I have implemented and I couldn't access session or request objects.

```
from django.http import HttpRequest

class DataBaseRouter:
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        request = HttpRequest()
        if request.session['user']=="Value":
            return 'second'
        return first

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
       request = HttpRequest()
        if request.session['user']=="Value":
            return 'second'
        return first
```

I expect to access Session variables or request object just like we can access them in Views or a way of injecting request object into db_for_read and db_for_write functions of the Database router class.

Comment: good day:

You've seen some of  django-tenant-schema.  -> https://django-tenant-schemas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/# ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is models can be accessed outside of the context of a view, and DbRouters are general purpose, and not multi-tenant by default.

You can do the logic yourself to manually choose a database within your views. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/multi-db/#manually-selecting-a-database

You could abstract a lot of this logic either yourself, or using a library like django-rest if you need a more structured pattern to follow.

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/

Comment: By any chance can we change/Add new Variable to Model Meta class at the model level so that we can access them

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `django-middleware-global-request` package [link](https://snyk.io/advisor/python/django-middleware-global-request#package-footer) to access the request object in your database router.